# Correct deleted and added folder to a rename which occurred far back in history

Tags: git, rename, git-rewrite-history

I moved a folder `projectname/stuff/*.py` to `projectname/projectname/stuff/*.py`, where `projectname/.git/` is the base folder of the repository. That original folder rename was apparently registered as a delete of the folder with the subsequent addition of newly created files nearly (but not exactly) identical to the original deleted files. I did not notice the problem at the time and it is now a few months and hundreds of commits later.

I can no longer merge in or diff against changes from other branches that exist from before that split, because. Is there a simple way to fix this so I can merge changes from the other branches without going through and modifying every commit in my history?

Answer (score 0):

Git does not explicitly store moves (and by extension renames). Instead, it always records the removal of one file and the addition of another. It detects moves and renames by calculating the similarity of files that have been deleted and added. So part of the good news is you won't have to rewrite your history to accomplish this.

Instead, you need to tell the diff or the merge to look for renamed files. In diff, you'd use the `--find-renames` [flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---find-renamesltngt) and in merge you'd use the `recursive` strategy with the `find-renames` [options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-find-renamesltngt) set.

```
git diff --find-renames[=<n>] 
git merge -s recursive -Xfind-renames[=<n>]
```

Both can accept an optional value to express how similar files need to be. By default this is 50%. You can set this by making `<n>` the similarity you're looking for. For example `--find-renames=40%` to say it's a match if at least 40% of the lines in the file are the same. Be very careful of turning it up too high, it's very easy to get false positives.

This options is usually turned on by default. It is is turned on already, another common cause of this issue is massive white space changes in the files you're working with (line ending change, tabs to spaces, indentation change) that push it over that 50% threshold. In these cases, you can invoke one of the white space control options (for [diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff-ignore-space-at-eol) and [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-ignore-space-change)) to help, but this often requires some cleanup after the fact, so you might want to add the `--no-commit` option for merges like this so you can clean up any white space issues before you commit.

Comment: Note that merge *always* has rename detection turned on; it's set to 50% by default. Adding `-Xfind-renames=<number>` just changes the threshold. Git diff used to have rename detection off by default, but the default was changed to "on" (at 50%) in Git 2.9. There's another configuration option, `diff.renameLimit`, that limits the depth of the rename-detection file queue. Setting this to an explicit zero tells Git "do as much as you can".